# Put a video into a UIView with push , start controls in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to put video in to the simple view and I want to push, start that video. I code for that. My video is playing into the view. But problem is I cannot push or start that video and when I go from one viewcontroller to another viewcontroller video start in background. Video also repeat all time not stop. my code for this is here:

```
  import UIKit
  import AVKit
  import AVFoundation

  class ComingSoonViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var videoview: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var nextBtn: UIButton!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  }
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let videoURL = URL(string: "http://conceptioni.in/DonorPlus/public/assets/1168255646_new.mp4")
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.videoview.bounds
    self.videoview.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()

   }
 }
```

please Help.Thank you in advance.

Comment: I want to push this one unable to understand

Comment: I want to push and start video run time.

Comment: where is your PUSH code